# Do you have any idea what matrix space is?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

Can someone explain what matrix space is by a given example. Is it a set of number?

Comment: Should we assume you know what matrices are?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix spaces are *vector spaces*: See the entry for [Vector Spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Matrices) in Wikipedia, and you'll find that a matrix space is a vector space.

> "A vector space is a mathematical structure  formed by a collection of elements called vectors [and in this context, vectors can be matrices, polynomials...], which may be added together and multiplied ("scaled") by numbers, called scalars in this context. Scalars are often taken to be real numbers..."

A matrix space, like vector spaces in general, consists of a set of $M_{m\times n}$ of matrices whose entries are from a field of numbers, which is closed under matrix addition and scalar multiplication. See [Basic Operations: Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations)

An example would be the set of all real $2\times 2$ matrices together with matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The vector space of matrices (with entries from some field F) of a given order would be a matrix space(over that field), denoted by $ M(m\times n,F) $.  I am assuming you know what a Vector space is.You can just put $ m=n=2 $ and $ F= \mathbb R $ get a good picture of such spaces yourself. I hope this is what you are looking for.